# Проблема с указание пути к аудиозаписи th:src (THYMELEAF, SPRING MVC)

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

У меня есть папка с аудиозаписями под названием audio_folder, в ней хранятся аудиозаписи, так же у меня есть сущность AudioEntity, с помощью неё я сохраняю такие данные как путь к файлу, название файла, его идентификатор и UUID, (UUID нужен для того чтобы не было конфликта в названиях, к примеру при добавлении в папку аудиозаписей с одним и тем же названием несколько раз). Файлы отлично сохраняются на сервере и добавляются в папку, но есть один нюанс, при попытке получить файлы и прослушать сами аудиозаписи, я сталкиваюсь с кое-какой трудностью, я вижу сам плеер, но прослушать музыку не могу, не подумайте, путь я получаю верный, в качестве доказательств я сделал отдельную html разметку в которой указал в точности такой же путь но он не был связан с проектом и музыка прослушивалась на ура, но при попытке указать путь с помощью th:src всё идёт к неудаче, вот примеры:

Такой плеер я имею:

[image]

[image]

А вот такой должен быть как вы понимаете:

main.html: (этот та самая рабочая разметка)

```
<audio controls>
<source src="audio_folder\436af921ae45482f80add78d14abae65.EminemMockingbird.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

home.html (та самая не рабочая разметка):

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" name="file">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
</form>

эта форма отвечает за добавление файлов на сервер

<audio th:each="audio : ${audios}" controls>
<source th:src="@{audio_folder\ + (*{audio.uuid + '.' + audio.name})}"/>
</audio>

эта форма отвечает за получения всех данных о аудиозаписях    

<div th:each="audio : ${audios}">
<p th:text="*{audio.path + audio.uuid + '.' + audio.name}">
</div>

а этот div я сделал для проверки верности пути к файлу
```

Как вы видите, проблема кроется не в контроллерах\сервисах, из дива для проверки я получаю такой путь: (поэтому контроллеры и сервисы я не показал, смысла в этом не вижу ведь свою задачу они выполняют идеально)

> C:\Users\SystemX\eclipse-workspace\spotify\lib\src\main\resources\audio_folder\22b1dda9499a4e4d8074005766691ff4.EminemMockingbird.mp3

на него просьба не обращать внимание, верный путь который работает в main.html такой:

> audio_folder\22b1dda9499a4e4d8074005766691ff4.EminemMockingbird.mp3

но он не работает в home.html, я считаю что проблема кроется в th:src, я этом уверен на 99%, я очень не опытен в работе с путями (src\th:src) где конкретно я напортачил я не знаю поэтому обращаюсь за помощью сюда, решать проблему не могу со вчерашнего дня (решал где-то до 3-4 часов ночи :( ) результат очевиден, я не прошу решения проблемы, мне будет достаточно если вы укажите на мои некоторые ошибки и дадите хотя бы наводку, прошу многого, знаю, но я буду очень благодарен

Comment: Попробуйте поменять обратный слеш на прямой - **audio_folder/**.

Comment: А что вообще пишет консоль?

Comment: попробовал как вы сказали, не помогло, в консоли пишет лишь это:
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval('audio_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        audios
        (name,path,uuid,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.id,
        a1_0.name,
        a1_0.path,
        a1_0.uuid 
    from
        audios a1_0

Comment: Что-то с базой данных связано, вместо имён, путей и айди записываются знаки вопроса, может из-за этого не получается.